# Is it possible to define a TTL on Riak CS?

Tags: riak-cs

I'm using Riak CS (Cloud Storage) to store files and I want them to expire using a TTL. I'm OK with defining the same TTL value for all the files, e.g. 1 week.

From what I've understood, Riak CS uses 2 backends:

- bitcak for binary data
- leveldb for metadata

I know bitcask supports defining a TTL, meaning binary data will be cleaned on a regular basis.

Is it possible to achieve the same with leveldb, i.e. for metadata?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LevelDB does not have such TTL feature so it won't work. If you want all object names disappear from list (a bucket), lifecycle API is a suitable interface of S3 but it's not yet implemented.